# Floating point precision in Go vs Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, floating-point

I'm just learning go now, and the tutorial gave this example:

```golang
    myNum := 0.1234

    // this evaluates to false
    if myNum == math.Pow(math.Sqrt(myNum), 2) {
        println(true)
    } else {
        println(false)
    }

    // this evalues to true
    if math.Abs(myNum/math.Pow(math.Sqrt(myNum), 2)-1) < 0.000000000000001 {
        println(true)
    } else {
        println(false)
    }
```

Now it was said that the former doesn't evaluate to true because floats are approximations of decimal values. But why ... exactly doesn't that work?

The exact same example does work in python, so I'm a little confused. It's bugging me that for some 'simple' arithmetic like this, which a computer should excel at, we have to take these extra precautionary measures

```py
a = 0.12345
a == math.sqrt(a ** 2) # evaluates to True
```

Comment: I think the real question here is why it works in Python; my best guess is the complier sees `sqrt(n)^2` and elides it entirely. What you're seeing in Go isn't specific to Go, it's just normal floating-point arithmetic which has limits to its precision.

Comment: What is your question? Why it doesn't work in Go or why it works in Python?

Comment: What does “work in python” mean? Both report true?

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, both report true

Comment: David, Print the values `0.1234, myNum, math.Pow(math.Sqrt(myNum), 2)` with at least 17 digits of significance to see details.

Comment: What “precautionary measures” do you think you need? On the face of it, this code checks whether the square of the square root of a number equals the number. Mathematically, yes, it does, so there is no need to use a program for that. The things floating-point is commonly used for do not generally need tests for equality. When a video game emulates physics to plot the course of a ball, it does not need an answer exactly equal to something. It just needs to get close enough to appear realistic. If you think you need exact answers, you may not be using floating-point for what it is designed for.

Comment: Your Python code doesn't match the Go code. In Go, you're computing the square of a square root. In Python, you compute the square root of a square.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You're right. I totally turned that around. After trying the right thing in python it also doesn't work. stupid mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now it was said that the former doesn't evaluate to true because floats are approximations of decimal values. But why ... exactly doesn't that work?

In the IEEE-754 binary64 format, which I believe Go uses, the closest representable value to .1234 is 0.12339999999999999580335696691690827719867229461669921875 (8891907104280307/2<sup>56</sup>). The closest representable value to its square root is 0.351283361405005933875145274214446544647216796875 (6328158462100160/2<sup>54</sup>). The closest representable value to the square of that is 0.123400000000000009681144774731365032494068145751953125 (8891907104280308/2<sup>56</sup>).

What has happened is that each operation had to round its result to a representable value, losing some accuracy in the process. In this case, it is not even an issue of using binary or floating-point: Square roots are generally not representable in finite numerical formats, so they necessarily lose accuracy.

> The exact same example does work in python…

The Python documentation does not specify floating-point arithmetic precisely. Implementations vary. You might need to specify a specific implementation to get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes sense. Side question; does a calculator for example use a different format than IEEE-754 then? As they provide the 'true' numbers

Comment: @DavidBrouwer: Calculators do not provide “true” numbers. Many of their errors are concealed. For example, they may use 12 digits internally but only show you ten, so the rounding errors do not get big enough to see until you have done many operations or know how to expose the errors. Some of their errors do not trigger your surprise because they may use decimal and so get answers rounded the way you expect from working in decimal yourself. But I guarantee that if you take the square root of two on a calculator, it will not compute the full numerical result, since it is infinitely long.